# Condição else sendo chamada no momento errado

Tags: java, if, else

Atualmente estou tendo problemas com um código de um trabalho. Minha classe ELSE está sendo sempre executada, mas somente quando eu escolho a opção referente ao primeiro IF.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BikeFit2
{
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
    String tipoBike, mtb, spd;
    double antebraco, cavalo, tamanhoQuadro, distanciaSelimQuidao;
    double diferencaSelimQuidao, tamanhoPedivela;
    int elasticidade, tamanhoPe, idade, freqMin, freqMax;

    System.out.println("Bem vindo!");
    System.out.println ("Insira o tipo de bicicleta, sendo: \n\rMTB para Mountain Bike  \n\rSPD para Road Bike");
    tipoBike = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insira a idade do ciclista:");
        idade = input.nextInt();

    spd = "SPD";
        if (tipoBike.equals(spd)){
            System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
            cavalo = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

            System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
            antebraco = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
            elasticidade = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

            System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
            tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

            System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);
    }
        mtb = "MTB";
        if (tipoBike.equals(mtb)){
            System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
            cavalo = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

            System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
            antebraco = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
            elasticidade = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

            System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
            tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

            System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);
    }


        else{
            System.out.println("Opção selecionada errada, tente de novo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vinda!

Comment: Posso estar bem enganado, mas esse teu else está somente no último if. Tu teria que fazer um else if no MTB e ai sim o else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua condição `else` está sendo chamada por que o `tipoBike` é diferente de `"MTB"`. Você deve colocar um `else` antes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BikeFit2
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        String tipoBike, mtb, spd;
        double antebraco, cavalo, tamanhoQuadro, distanciaSelimQuidao;
        double diferencaSelimQuidao, tamanhoPedivela;
        int elasticidade, tamanhoPe, idade, freqMin, freqMax;

        System.out.println("Bem vindo!");
        System.out.println ("Insira o tipo de bicicleta, sendo: \n\rMTB para Mountain Bike  \n\rSPD para Road Bike");
        tipoBike = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Insira a idade do ciclista:");
            idade = input.nextInt();

        spd = "SPD";
        mtb = "MTB";

        if (tipoBike.equals(spd)){
            System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
            cavalo = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

            System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
            antebraco = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
            elasticidade = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

            System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
            tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

            System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);
        }
        else if (tipoBike.equals(mtb)){
            System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
            cavalo = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

            System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
            antebraco = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

            System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
            elasticidade = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

            System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
            tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

            System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Opção selecionada errada, tente de novo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Aconselho você a usar um `switch`, melhora a legibilidade do código. Outra dica, cuidado com a tabulação do seu código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BikeFit2
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        String tipoBike, mtb, spd;
        double antebraco, cavalo, tamanhoQuadro, distanciaSelimQuidao;
        double diferencaSelimQuidao, tamanhoPedivela;
        int elasticidade, tamanhoPe, idade, freqMin, freqMax;

        System.out.println("Bem vindo!");
        System.out.println ("Insira o tipo de bicicleta, sendo: \n\rMTB para Mountain Bike  \n\rSPD para Road Bike");
        tipoBike = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Insira a idade do ciclista:");
        idade = input.nextInt();


        switch (tipoBike)
        {
            case "SPD":
                System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
                cavalo = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

                System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
                antebraco = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

                System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
                elasticidade = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

                System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
                tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

                System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);
                 break;

            case "MTB":
                System.out.println ("Insira o comprimento do Cavalo:");
                cavalo = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho cavalo \n\r", cavalo);

                System.out.println("Insira o tamanho do Antebraço");
                antebraco = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho Antebraço\n\r", antebraco);

                System.out.println("Insira o valor da Elasticidade de 0 a 10");
                elasticidade = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf ("%s valor elasticidade\n\r", elasticidade);

                System.out.println("Insira a numeração do tenis\n\r");
                tamanhoPe = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf ("%s tamanho tenis:\n\r", tamanhoPe);

                System.out.printf("%s é idade do ciclista", idade);

                break;
             default:
                System.out.println("Opção selecionada errada, tente de novo!");
        }               

    }
}
```

Comment: Por que o negativo? Qual o problema da resposta?